# Managing Roles for multiple SP (Service Providers) in SSO based application

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp, aws-sso

Need information on how to use roles in SSO based application while supporting multiple SP (sso clients)

I am working on a SSO based architecture by using CAS protocol. How do I manage roles across different SP (Service Providers) for the same user. I have 2 Service Providers e.g Sp1 and Sp2 applications. I have a User -> User1 who should have simple "user" role in Sp1 but has "admin" role in Sp2. How can I manage my IdP - Shibboleth or any other to release relevant role for the user ?

Comment: Are the applications protected with Shibboleth SP (as indicated by the tag) and you're trying to integrate with Shibboleth IDP? If so, why is CAS involved? Or are you a CAS SP integrating with a Shib IDP via the latter's CAS protocol support?